# Do Sunglasses always give a penalty to visibility?

Tags: equipment, shadowrun-sr5, vision-and-light

The Environmental Compensation Table on page 175 lists that Sunglasses shift glare conditions one row up and light conditions one row down.

Would that mean in perfect conditions (no glare, full light), the sunglasses would always give a penalty to visibility (effectively reducing Light to "Partial Light")?

Comment: Isn't that the purpose of shades?

Comment: I was wondering, simply because it seems...stupid to wear shades if it always give a penalty

Comment: @MechMK1 Does the game also make available, like, fashionable designer sunglasses that *only* just look cool? (But if the game does *not*, I'm unsurprised: one of the trade-offs in a cyberpunk game is supposed to be style over substance. I mean, even if that style gets you killed because you couldn't hit the dude in the semi-dark due to your sunglasses, everyone at your funeral will say you looked really cool dying with your sunglasses on!)

Comment: Not RAW, but I'd say that sunglasses IMPROVE my vision on a sunny day.

Comment: @HeyICanChan yes, it does. You can make wearable that looks like anything you want in the setting, specially if they are connected to the matrix.

Comment: @CM_Dayton That's because sunny day = glare

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**In a word: Yes**

The point of Sunglasses is to shade your eyes against glare, and there are specific cases in which this is useful.

"Perfect Conditions" as you describe (full light, no glare) is basically "Indoors, all the lights are on." In that case, yes. Sunglasses would give a penalty to visibility. Y'know...it's why you don't generally wear sunglasses indoors.

Per the RAW, Sunglasses are a tradeoff, but a potentially useful one.

The further down the table you go, the worse the penalties get. So if you are in an area with Full Light and Moderate Glare (i.e. outside on a very sunny day), you're taking a -3 penalty. Slap on a pair of sunglasses and you switch to Partial Light, Weak Glare, reducing the penalty to -1. So, sunglasses are useful in the exact circumstances in which they are useful in real life.

In general, Flare Compensation is superior to sunglasses...but it's also more then 3x the price (glasses + flare comp).

Comment: Wow. I've never heard of another game that *penalizes* folks for fighting outside in sunlight.  I guess it ain't called ***Shadow**run* for nothin'.

Comment: Note the phrasing: "take only the most severe environmental condition and use the associated modifier. **If there are two or more environmental modifiers tied for most severe, bump the modifier up a category**"

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, they do.

If we check the table, sunglasses are made to reduce enviromental modifiers from Light/Glare.

Since they *shift* the **Glare** condition one row up, that means a *No Glare* condition remains the same. But they also *shift* the **Light** condition one row down, the ("perfect") *Full Light* condition goes down to *Partial Light*.

> **Environmental**
>
> To determine the Environmental modifier, take only the most severe environmental condition and use the associated modifier. If there are two or more environmental modifiers tied for most severe, bump the modifier up a category. Note that Range is an environmental modifier.

```
| Visibility              | Light/Glare                   | Wind           | Range  | Modifier
| Clear                   | Full Light/No Glare           | None or Breeze | Short  | -
| Light Rain/Fog/Smoke    | Partial Light/Weak Glare      | Light Winds    | Medium | -1
| Moderate Rain/Fog/Smoke | Dim Light/Moderate Glare      | Moderate Winds | Long   | -3
| Heavy Rain/Fog/Smoke    | Total Darkness/Blinding Glare | Strong Winds | Extreme  | -6
| Combination of two or more conditions at the -6 level row -10
```

Even though *Light* and *Glare* are tracked on the same column, they are different conditions in the game, and the worst of the two should apply, causing a **-1 Modifier on ranged attacks**

What you need are **Sunglasses equipped with Low-Light Vision**, which removes the penalty completely.

> **Low-Light Vision**
>
> Treat Partial Light and Dim Light as Full Light

Comment: There are a ton of other viable combinations....like just plain glasses with Flare Compensation. Flatly better than Sunglasses in every way. And cheaper than the combo you suggested. (And sunglasses with low-light vision would still leave you blind in Dim Light...as the glasses would shift that to Total Darkness, which low-light vision can't see in)

Comment: @guildsbounty that would be a matter of *which applies first*, which is subject to table variation. Does the enhancement or the inherent effect applies first? Depending on the order, you remain in Partial Light or Total Darkness. It is known that enhancements will replace whatever natural vision you had without it, so i (personally) would go that the enhancement replaces Dim/Partial to Full Light, except in Darkness, where the enhancement takes no effect.